# Model for markets with friction

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, friction

Is there a stochastic model for describing how equities behave in markets with trading fees, and if so what model is most commonly used?  I'm envisioning something similar to the Black Scholes model, except that the differential of the equity should include some term that captures these fees.

Comment: Please be more accurate, all markets have trading fees. What is exactly the application you have in mind? they are models for optimal execution, optimal market making, hedging under transaction costs, or the interaction of fees and bid-ask spread effects from the viewpoint of an exchange.